# How to find rest call made by powershell cmdlet?

Tags: rest, powershell

We are having powershell module for our storage server which makes rest calls behind the screen to fetch details. In background it will call Invoke-RestMethod, I need to know the parameters it used for Invoke-RestMethod . I tried Start-Transcript but it did not show the cmdlets called in background.

The reason is i need this is to use the same rest call in my ansible script Uri method.From the API documentation it is difficult to find properties for some of the action.

Is there any way i can find Rest api header and properties used by the cmdlet?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using Fiddler to capture the REST calls.

You would most likely need to decrypt the HTTPS traffic. This can be done in Fiddler by going to Tools -> Options -> HTTPS -> Decrypt HTTPS traffic  (install the man-in-the-middle root cert)